# Bar plot in R with multiple columns

Tags: r, bar-chart

i want to plot side by side bar plot of below information where i have multiple coloumns.
I know how to plot for single column ut not getting how to plot for multiple columns.
Here i also want to change the A with (5.5 -6 ) and B with 6.0-6.5 and so on till F as >8.

```
Vendor  A             B          C            D         E            F
Full    2.164179104 0.447761194 0.179104478 0.059701493 0           0
RM      2.660428803 1.119464038 0.47877197  0.178534969 0.044064211 0.003246692
AR      0.2823      0.2614      0.2046      0.1086      0.054       0.0218
GEM_1   1.179104478 0.298507463 0.164179104 0.059701493 0.014925373 0
GEM_2   1.626865672 0.388059701 0.179104478 0.059701493 0.014925373 0
GK      0.835820896 0.268656716 0.149253731 0.059701493 0.014925373 0
UH      1.119402985 0.358208955 0.164179104 0.059701493 0.014925373 0
```

Graph which I am expecting is something like below:
[image: output of above data]

Comment: Some formatting issue  . Please let me know if further details needed

Comment: Please provide some of your data in a useable format to have a good [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). You can provide some of your data using `dput()` or even just `dput(head(df))`, where df is your dataframe. What code have you tried so far?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Barplot with multiple columns in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37931327/barplot-with-multiple-columns-in-r)